# how to add values from var to listview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public static bool loadFileview(Int64 uname,out string[] filename,out string[] extn)
{
        bool b = false;
        SCPEntities ent = new SCPEntities();

        filename = null;
        extn = null;

        var data = (from n in ent.User_Data where n.Account_Num == uname select new { n.File_Name, n.Extn }).ToList();
        int i = 0;

        foreach (var v in data)
        {
            filename[i] = v.File_Name;
            extn[i] = v.Extn;
            i++;
        }

        if(liv1!=n)
        {
            b = true;
            // liv = data;
        }

        return b;
    }
}
```

method call

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string[] fname;
        string[] extn;
        Int64 uname = 12121;
        bool b = false;

       b= home.loadFileview(uname, out fname,out extn);

       if (b)
       {
           for (int count = 0; count <fname.Length; count++)
           {
               ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem(fname[count]);
               listItem.SubItems.Add(extn[count]);
               FileListView.Items.Add(listItem);
           }
}
```

I want to bind `filename` & `extn` to listview control listview11 dynamically, how?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] fname;
    string[] extn;
    Int64 uname = 12121;
    bool b = false;

   b= home.loadFileview(uname, out fname,out extn);

   if (b)
   {
       for (int count = 0; count <fname.Length; count++)
       {
           ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem (new[] { fname[count], extn[count]})
           FileListView.Items.Add(listItem);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest wrapping the code in `if(!IsPostBack){}` also.